# Most frequent number in array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, numbers

I need to have a method that returns the most frequent number from an array of integer in Java. If 2 numbers are the most frequent, I want the method to return the highest number.

Examples:

- `[4,1,4,1,3]` -> `4` (not `1`)
- `[5,2,6,5,5]` -> `5`

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the solution is to create the Map with Integer as a key and Integer as the value. You will have to iterate through the array and increase the amount of the numbers in a map.

```
Integer[] arr = {4, 1, 4, 1, 3};
Map<Integer,Integer> integersCount = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

for (Integer i : arr){
    if (!integersCount.containsKey(i))
        integersCount.put(i, 1);
    else
        integersCount.put(i, integersCount.get(i) + 1);
    }
```

After that you can go through the map and remember the position of the element which has the greatest value.

For another solution I recommend counting the numbers in another array - read about "counting sort".

Comment: Is there an other method, I'm a beginner in Java... :)

Comment: @ThomasJomphe another advice is to read about counting sort.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a hashmap then iterate through the array and with each index of the array you store the array index value as the key, then the hashmap value will be a counter for how often you see that key in the array.  Once you run through the array, create two variables, one will keep track of the highest value in the hashmap and the other will keep track of how many there are.  If there is only one that has the highest value, you then iterate through the hashmap again to find that value, and then the key will be the answer.  If there are multiple keys that have the highest value, you create a list and then reiterate through the hasmap and store every key whose value is equal to the highest.  Then you iterate though the linked list to find the highest value.

There is the logic.  If you need me to write out the actual code, I can.  Just lmk.

Comment: The time complexity of this is O(n)

Answer (score 0):

In statistics, this function is called `mode` which you can easily achieve with `Stream` since Java 8:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(4,1,4,4,3,1);
Integer mostFrequented = list.stream().reduce(BinaryOperator.maxBy((o1, o2) -> 
    Collections.frequency(list, o1) - Collections.frequency(list, o2))).orElse(null);

System.out.println(mostFrequented); // Prints 4
```

Comment: nice api use collections/streams

Comment: I do like this answer for its brevity. But it is very, very, very inefficient due to constantly calculating the frequency of the elements. I tried it out with 50k random elements (in a range of 1 to 20) and it took already 12 seconds whereas it should be milliseconds ...

Comment: Pretty horrifying to iterate the entire collection twice per comparison... and I think you're comparing 4 three different times! I'm also surprised `.orElse(null)` will assign to an `int`.

Comment: @AjahnCharles: A bunch of typos happens and I have corrected them, please don't bring the emotions here. I worked with the sample the OP has provided. Moreover, I never said it was the most efficient way (moreover `Stream::reduce` iterates once whereas `Collection::frequency` has the complexity `O(n)` - where did you get I iterate 4 times) - I bring the idea using [tag:java-stream]. I appreciate your feedback, but not the way you tell me.

Comment: @Nikolas - You've added the emotion in your reading. It's perfectly reasonable to note for other readers that this answer is very inefficient. `reduce` will apply your comparison to each 4 in the original collection, i.e. 3 times (at some points you're even comparing 4 to another 4).

Comment: Merging your answer with Wojciech's would give a nice solution. His answer gives you a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>`, which you could then operate on similarly (untested): `Optional<Integer> mode = frequencies.entrySet().stream().reduce(BinaryOperator.maxBy(e1,e2) -> e1.getValue() - e2.getValue()).map(e -> e.getKey())`

Answer (score 0):

```
 Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();    
for (Integer integer : array){
if (map.containsKey(integer))
    map.put(integer, map.get(integer) + 1);
else
       map.put(integer,1);
}

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.keySet());
Collections.sort(list,new Comparator<Integer>() {
       @Override
       public int compareTo(Intger num1, Integer num2) {
           if(map.get(num1)>map.get(num2))
              return -1;
            if(map.get(num1)<map.get(num2))
              return 1;
            if(num1 > num2)
                 return -1;
            if(num1<num2)
                return 1;
              return 0;
          }
      });
  System.out.println(list.get(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

bad way BUT simple to uderstand to you and ME ;)

```
int arr[] = {5,2,6,5,5};
int repeat[]={0,0,0,0,0};
int index=0;
for(int i:arr){ 
    for(int j:arr){
        if(j==i)
            repeat[index]++;
        }
    index++;
    }  
//print repeat array to find out
for(int i:repeat){
     System.out.println(i);
}
```

complete it yourself ;)